# URL decode in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

i have a string named url i.e

```
NSString *url = @"http://sound17.mp3pk.com/indian/barfi/%5BSongs.PK%5D%20
              Barfi%20-%2001%20-%20Barfi!.mp3";
```

Now I am downloading this song and to save this I need to specify filename.I want the filename in such a way that It should take the file name itself from url.like in this url,It should take `%5BSongs.PK%5D%20
                  Barfi%20-%2001%20-%20Barfi!.mp3` which is the file name in the url but should not be consist of Url formatters.

what I am doing is

```
Dest_path=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents/a3"];

result =[Dest_path stringByAppendingString:@".mp3"];
helper = [DownloadHelper download:url withTargetPath:result withDelegate:self];
```

Comment: The title of your question is not of much help. Would be a good excercise to coin what you want to know in just one phrase.

Comment: thanx for your suggestions.please check now ..is it helpful to understand!

Comment: @PhillipMills I am so going to use that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
NSString *URLString = @"http://sound17.mp3pk.com/indian/barfi/%5BSongs.PK%5D%20Barfi%20-%2001%20-%20Barfi!.mp3";
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSString *filename = [[[URL path] lastPathComponent] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//=> [Songs.PK] Barfi - 01 - Barfi!.mp3
```

Note that you cannot always get a useful filename from just a URL, if the content is dynamic (e.g. something like `http://example.com/getsong?q=foobar`).

*Edit:* A better way to get a file name from an arbitrary URL would be to make a request and inspect the `Content-Disposition` [HTTP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) of the response.

Comment: You should probably note that there are better ways to get a filename, e.g. HTTP headers.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII can you give me link or some other information.

Comment: @omz on that case what should I do ? or do you have any other alternative to give filename.